# VPN Configuration issue with internet pass through not showing home network

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, iphone, desktop-computer

Ok a little history.

I am a windows guy and way back in 08 I had a file/VPN server running on Win Server 03. I used it to secure the connection when on say Mcdonaolds WiFi on my iPhones and also to access files for my business.

Everything worked great.
I could surf the web through and also access printers and mapped drives like I was sitting in my house.

Now that I've given Ubuntu a chance all I've managed is to get OpenVPN working for my iphone but it is only passing the internet connection not actually letting me on my network.

I had that trouble with Server 08 but was able to fix it because, well I'm a GUI guy and haven't used command prompts since Win 98.

Can some please tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. The story is nice but doesn't help so much to understand the problem, Read the "[ask]" page, to have some hints more about how to help us to understand your problem and [edit] your question adding some informations more, e.g. how you configured the VPN, if you have problem/checked with other computers inside the VPN... You can even install a virtual machine (with `virtualbox`) downloading a system ready to be used, and check as if it was another computer.

Comment: I used this site to set the openvpn up. It was the standard way of doing it.        https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-linux-14-04-or-16-04-lts/#comments                                                                                Right now on my iphone I can use the vpn to establish a secure tunnel through the internet but not to access the network. Im trying to make so I can use my DLNA app to view my plex server on the go like I was at home actually on the network. I cant get openvpn to work correctly on my laptop so I cant test any other device.